# Run checklink utility of w3c

Tags: iis

I 've install w3c checklink utility to check my website for broken links. but i am really confused with its parameters. I just want to get number of broken link of my site.but i don't know how to run this utility.

would you help me?

Edited: I tried these commands:

```
$ checklink -s -b -D 2 http://mysite.com >site-report

$ checklink -b -D 2 http://mysite.com >site-report
```

but a long report is created and store in site-report file. i just want the number of broken links not what they are.

Comment: The gods of server fault help those who help themselves.  What have you tried already, and in what way was it not to your needs?  Show you've read *something*, and you'll get a better class of answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that `linkcheck` has the ability to report *only* a count of broken links.  It's not really something that is generally useful -- if you've got broken links, typically you'd like to know what they are so you can fix them.

Comment: you are right,but i need it evaluate my site between some other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You could just post-process the output of checklink with grep, awk or perl or something similar to count the number of broken links. e.g:

```
checklink ... | grep "The link is broken" | wc -l
```